# Trends for job vacancies and technologies

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, trends

I think it would be useful to have a tool similar to Trends, but for jobs - i.e. a chart to show what techonologies are in demand (how many vacancies include it), the total number of vacancies, the number of vacancies by categories (front end/back end/data science/desktop/etc), etc.
What do you think?

Comment: Stack Overflow won't be able to deliver this, as they can only base such statistics on the companies advertising on the site. That is a poor base, since certain kind of companies favouring certain technologies might decide to advertise on SO specifically.